# exists a function in openpyxl that do the same than when you drag in excel?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Does there exist a function that does the exact same thing than when you drag in excel? I tried to use copy but if it's a function it just let me the same function and I want to move the rows.

For example, I have the cell A1 with the value "=B1+B3-C1" i want a function that get the value and if I'm moving it 3 rows down the value has to be "=B4+B6-C4". it's not diff to make a new one but if it exists, I want to use it.

Comment: In Oenpyxl, if you move a formula then you need to change its reference(s) yourself if needed. With Openpyxl you're just changing the value or formula in a cell. Updating of references when moving a formula to another cell is an Excel feature.

Comment: yeah, i know, thats why i ask if there were a function that do the updating

Comment: No, None in the [Openpyl Utils](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.html?highlight=utils#module-openpyxl.utils).